# Seting color of UI element before Activity is started

Tags: android, android-activity, mvp

I am using MVP and in all screens statusBar is set to be red. So, in styles.xml statusBar is set to red. The only screen where it needs to be white is Splash Screen (should be same color as background).

If I set it in initView or onCreate as I would normaly do it, statusBar is shown first in red and after a second or two the color is changed to right one (white). This looks not nice to the user.

I tried to set it from Presenter onCreate method, but I can never get rid of this 2-seconds delay.

So, the questions is: how to set UI elements proporties in Activity (View) before the Activity is started? This is a slightly specific case, becase it is about first Screen that is shown to the user.

I hope it was clear what the problem is, I could also post some more code if needed.

```
    public void initViews() {
        splashRelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.rl_splash);
        setSplashScreenStatusBarColorOnStart(); //todo check with release how status bar looks like

    }
```

Comment: Add color in your xml.

Comment: I would like to do it but it has to be set on Activity start. Just for this activity needs to be same color as background (Splash Screen)

Comment: lifecycle callbacks onCreate() where you can initialise the Activity and get references to the views and set their view properties, including color.  Lifecycle callbacks onStart() and onResume() are also called before the Activity is actually displayed on screen so you can adjust properties their too

Comment: Can you provide us some example how you want to implement your task?

Comment: Hi everyone, just tried to explain it a bit more, if you need some details more please say

Comment: You can set different style specifically for your Splash Screen.

Comment: Yes, but not if client does not want it :)

Comment: If you try to do a findViewById before your activity binds the layout (puting it before setContentView()) it will crash with a nullpointer exception.